# Trying to change menu item text to an icon when active

Tags: javascript, menu, navigation

So this is my first question here.

I have 5 menu items and 5 icons. I have coded them like this.

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link currentactive" href=" index.html#getdemo">Get Demo</a>
<a class="nav-link2" href="index.html#getdemo"><img src="images/demo.png"></a>
</li>
```

The code above is the first section. I have 5 sections on the page. It is a one-page website. Different menu items go to different sections on the page with #id.

What I am trying to achieve here is, 
SHOW TEXT on the menu items. And HIDE ICON (the second ) when not active.

And when the menu item is active.
HIDE TEXT on the menu item, and show the ICON (the image).

Currently, the menu looks like this:
[image]

And I want to make it look like this:
[image]

And in case if you are wondering, how am I going to detect the active section on the page, I have already done that part using a JS found here. https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav

I think the solution to this is near to writing a script, 
For when the menu item is active, show **nav-link2** and hide **nav-link1**

But i am very lost how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply active class to the li and then apply the below styles:

```
<li class="nav-item currentactive">
<a class="nav-link" href=" index.html#getdemo">Get Demo</a>
<a class="nav-link2" href="index.html#getdemo"><img src="images/demo.png"></a>
</li>
```

Css

```
.currentactive .nav-link, .nav-link2 {
    display: none;
}

.curentactive .nav-link2, .nav-link  {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This did not exactly work the way you said. However, I could figure out the logic and could solve my problem with your advice. Thank you very much! :)